# How to use a for loop in shiny reactive

Tags: r, shiny

How could someone use a for loop within a reactive expression ?

I  mean if i want to build repeated procedure for a dataset that depend on users input values.

```
data <- reactive({ 
           for (i in 1:5) {initial_data$input$valuei}
            })
```

r you need to express this in another way?

Answer (score 2):

Are you list looking to change `valuei` each time in the loop? If so then the dollar sign operator isn't a good choice. You'll want to use proper list indexing. How about

```
data <- reactive({ 
    for (i in 1:5) {
        initial_data$input[[paste0("value",i]]
    }
})
```

of course that doesn't actually do anything with those values, but i wasn't sure what your intent was from your sample.

Comment: what if the columns are named?